# While inserting to table date going as 000000 in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with column datatype as `Date` in mysql database.
I want to insert dates in `'dd/mm/yyyy'` format so I used below query. When I use only the `SELECT`, the result set is showing correct. But when I use the `INSERT`, it is going as '000000' (the values inserted are all the `'0000-00-00'` date in `abc`).

The column I am selecting from (`completion_date`) is `varchar` datatype.

```
INSERT INTO abc 
    (maturity_date) -- Datatype Date for maturity_date column 
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(
        STR_TO_DATE(completion_date,    -- varchar
                    '%d/%m/%Y'), 
        '%d-%m-%Y') 
FROM XYZ ;
```

When if am using below script, data is inserted properly but format is 'yyyy/mm/dd'.

```
INSERT ...
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(completion_date , '%d-%m-%Y')
...
```

Is there any way to insert in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format with proper data?

example: `'21-01-2017'`

Comment: Show us the whole `INSERT` statement (by editing your question).

Comment: INSERT INTO abc (maturity_date)   -- Datatype Date for   maturity_date column
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(om.completion_date, '%d/%m/%Y') , '%d-%m-%Y')   maturity_date FROM XYZ

Comment: Is the type of `xyz.maturity_date` a `varchar`? Please edit the question and put the info there.

Comment: Give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE abc\G` (it's really called that?). Put this IN THE QUESTION! You can always edit your own question!

Comment: Ya it is varhcar, i have edited my question.

Comment: Dates should be stored in `DATEs`.  Non-standard output formats should be applied by `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(...)`.  The only format for the `DATE` datatype is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I'm having issues understanding the following sentence in your question: _want to insert date in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format so using below query but selecting result set is showing correct but while inserting it is going as '000000'_ How can the it be possible that **"...it is correct but showing '000000'..."**? Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/192910/edit) your question and try to rephrase it. We understand that English might not be your native language and that it might be difficult to express you issue. We do try to accommodate for that, but sometimes it is difficult for us.

Comment: @hot2use Thank you for you information. I have corrected the question but it showing as hold.   while inserting value going as ''0000-00-00', after reading some stuff and suggestion I got to know that only we can insert data in mysql as 'yyyy/mm/d' format.

Comment: I edited your question with some explanation. Please check and edit if I didn't explain the issue correctly.

Comment: @yper-trollᵀᴹ : it is correct, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL manual, DATE uses the YYYY-MM-DD format

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> Invalid DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00').

You can select dates out of your database and convert them to whatever format you want to display to your uses, but to store them you'll need to use the YYYY-MM-DD format that MySQL is expecting.